# laravel - correct query work in phpmyadmin, return null in app

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this code:

```
$abcd= DB::table('control')
        ->leftJoin('proces', 'proces.id_control', '=', 'control.id_control')
        ->select('control.id_risk', DB::raw("group_concat(proces.id_procedur) as prc"))
        ->where('control.id_theme', '=', $id)
        ->whereExists(function ($query) {
            $query->select('id_control')
            ->from('proces')   ->where('control.id_control','proces.id_control');
        })
        ->groupBy('control.id_risk')
        ->get();
```

This query work perfectly, when i wrote it in phpmyadmin, but when I try to execute it in app query return empty array. Where is problem

**UPDATE**

After i check how looks query from laravel there is one wrong

```
select `control`.`id_risk`, group_concat(proces.id_procedur) as prc from `control` left join `proces` on `proces`.`id_control` = `control`.`id_control` where `control`.`id_theme` = ? and exists (select `id_control` from `proces` where `control`.`id_control` = ?) group by `control`.`id_control`
```

First question mark is corrent beacue this $id(by the way variable is passing good value) but the second question mark should not be there.

Comment: Put 'toSql()' instead of 'get()' so you could see the sql statement which will be produced by eloquent. With that you can find out where the differences are.

Comment: try to print out your query `toSQL()` instead of `get()` and compare it with the query what you have written in phpmyadim. Also check `$id` is coming properly or not?

Comment: i update question

Comment: If you're using `whereExists` to verify that the left join is fulfilled (ie, the `proces` table was indeed joined) why not make it an inner join? Remove the `whereExists` and change `leftJoin` to `join`